# Ruby JSON gem (1.1.3) failed to install

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

This is the error I got:

```
MacBook-Pro:myapp marcamilly$ gem install json -v 1.1.3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/marcamilly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/Users/marcamilly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.4.0 -I/Users/marcamilly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/marcamilly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -Wall  -o parser.o -c parser.c
parser.rl:2:16: error: re.h: No such file or directory
In file included from parser.rl:3:
/Users/marcamilly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/st.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h"
parser.rl: In function ‘cParser_initialize’:
parser.rl:499: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
parser.rl:511: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
parser.rl:518: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/marcamilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/json-1.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/marcamilly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/json-1.1.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

Any thoughts on what how I can fix this?

I believe that I might have had json installed as apart of another project (a Rails project) previously, but now I am trying to install this specific one, to be used with Sinatra and this is the error I get.

Thanks.

Comment: Why install the json gem when JSON is part of the ruby standard library http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/json/1.9.2/JSON

Comment: @user420504 Because the particular project I am working on, requires that exact version to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had to have `ruby 1.8.7` chosen as the current version of Ruby before installing this gem.

I finally got it installed properly.